# Recorrer diccionario y guardar la clave del valor correspondiente

Tags: vb.net

Debo mostrar la hora máxima y a la hora que fue. Para almacenar los datos de temperaturas y horas utilizo un diccionario (**donde la temperatura es el valor y la hora es la clave**). Puedo extraer sin problemas la temperatura máxima utilizando la función Max(), pero no consigo guardar la hora en la que fue.

Si ingreso dos temperaturas y horas, (o 3), la hora que se guarda es la del ultimo dato ingresado.

```
**Sub InformeTemperaturaMAX(ByRef informeTemperatura As Dictionary(Of Byte, Double))
        ''KEY ---> HORA
        ''VALUE ---> TEMPERATURA
        Dim temp As Byte ''value
        Dim hora As Byte ''key
        For Each temperatura As KeyValuePair(Of Byte, Double) In informeTemperatura
            temp = informeTemperatura.Values.Max
            hora = temperatura.Key
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("La temperatura maxima es de: " & temp & "C" & " " & "a las " & hora & "hs. ")
    End Sub**
```

Comment: El for que sentido tiene, si con informeTemperatura.Values.Max ya sabes cual es la maxima? me parece que te pidieron hacerlo con un for, e ir comprobando manualmente si esa era la maxima o no.. y de esa forma, sabrias cual es la clave que tiene la maxima.. puede ser????

Comment: es verdad, no me habia percatado que el for estaba de mas, gracias por eso! lo que debo hacer es encontrar la clave de ese maximo valor